# Is there a way in Mocha JS to force file to run last

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm working with Mocha JS to test these calls I'm making to a database. However, there is one call that checks the number of objects being made in the database, because of this, I want this to be the last thing called to make sure everything has been made. Currently all the tests are spread across multiple files. Is there a way to do this aside from putting all the tests in one file, because I only know how to order via suites.

Comment: Order shouldn't matter in tests. If a test is dependent upon another test, it's not a good one.

Answer (score 0):

I would not try to perform such a check as a final check after all other tests have run, because:

1. Mocha is designed to work best with tests that are independent from one another. Mocha allows you to select tests to run so that if you have a failure you can run only those tests that failed. Tests that depend on other tests cannot be easily be run in isolation this way. You'd have to list the test you care about plus the tests in depends on, or craft a regular expression that matches them all but does not match the tests that are not needed.
2. You want to run a final test that checks whether all the earlier tests have created the expected number of objects. When we write test suites there is always a risk that a test will pass because of multiple bugs that hide each other's effects. The more code a single test covers (the greater its scope), the higher the risk. You could have test A that creates one extraneous object and test B that creates one less than expected. Each bug hides the effect of the other, and your suite passes. You should perform your object creation check at the end of each test. By reducing the scope you reduce the risk of having bugs hiding each other. If the code for the check is substantial, you could put it in a utility library loaded in each test file.
3. Furthermore, by having the check done at the end of every test, you know exactly where the problem is when your suite fails. If you have a general count check at the end and it does not match, then which test created more or less objects than expected? You have to hunt for it.